# Excel 2007 Need to copy column B to new row in Column A

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I need help. I have several 2007 worksheets with two column of data and many rows. I want to take the information in each row of column B and add it/move it as a new row under column A. Is this possible with a VBA? In other words, I don't want to have two columns. At the end of the day, I want everything in one column. If so, can someone help? Example (current worksheet):

```
Column A-------------- Column B
What's today?--------- Tuesday
What is this? ---------- It's an apple
What's your name?----My name is Mike
```

Expected result (there should be NO blank rows in between)

```
Column A
What's today?
Tuesday
What is this?
It's an apple
What's your name?
My name is Mike
```

Comment: Do you need get the result without VBA? You can add 2 index columns and sort them, if you need I can post answer here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following VBA code. It inserts a new row, then cut and paste the value of column B to the newly inserted row in column A.

```
Sub CutAndPaste()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    'Get last row with data
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'Row counter
    Dim i As Integer
    'Counter to start at 2nd row
    i = 2

    For x = 1 To LastRow
        'Insert new row
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Insert (xlShiftDown)
        'Cut and paste value from column B to inserted cell in column A
        Range("B" & x).Cut Range("A" & i)
        'Increase counter
        i = i + 2

    Next

End Sub
```

[image]